# Which order of nested layouts is most efficient in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, nested

I don't think I have really ever nested more than about three levels worth of Layouts (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`) in Android. I am not thinking about list items which also use a custom layout for `ListView` but just normal layouts for an activity.

To the point though, I was chatting with another developer about nesting layouts for a certain layout we were discussing and he seemed to think that even a few nested layouts really slowed down performance. I figured there is some truth but it cant be that much.

Does anyone have a more expert approach to this? Any input? Opinion?

Thanks.

UPDATE for those who found on Google:
The first answer below is a great resource. It looks like a lot and people seem to skip over answers like that but please check it out. Very valuable.

Comment: I would have thought more people would have referenced this issue and the wonderful answer below in order to produce more efficient apps. Perhaps the announcement of 3.1, the ADK, etc have now made this the least of peoples worries as they try to catch up with everything happening recently...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I guess there is no silver bullet for this but I will give you some tips:

1) **Try using the tools provided with the android sdk.**

I tend to analyze my layouts with `hierarchyviewer` and `layoutopt` trying to reduce the amount of `View` used and the height of the tree.

2) **Read Romain Guy's posts about `<include>`, `<merge>` and `<ViewStub>`**
These tags are not used often but they provide great speed "hacks".

- http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/
- http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/16/android-layout-tricks-4-optimize-part-2/

3) **Use `dmtracedump` and measure how long does it take to inflate a view.**

You can check how long it takes to inflate a view. Get an inflater and measure how long it takes to inflate each of your options.

Comment: you could add to the list another of Guy's suggestions: often nested `LinearLayouts` can be turned into one `RelativeLayout`. (I can't provide reference right now)

Comment: The `layoutopt` tool has been replaced by `lint`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8572055/133153.

Answer (score 1):

I havent done any proper testing to support this, still, I believe that android was design to use nesting Layouts in order to provide adequate UI's to the user, its practically the only way to support multiple screens so I wouldn't really worry about which is the most efficient, just that it looks the way it should.

Any other kind of bad programming practice would probably have a bigger effect in efficiency than layout nesting.

Comment: +1 (When I get more votes) Very true but at the same time, you should not have to change layouts much in order to support multiple screen sizes provided the graphics are designed for the different screen sizes.

Comment: What I meant was that with adequate layout nesting you can almost always have only one layout for all screen sizes and let it adapt automatically

Answer (score 0):

The difference will be much more important when you use such a layout for every item in a ListView for instance. Hopefully [this simple example](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html) showed you that getting to know your layouts is the best way to learn how to optimize your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you a full answer, but Romain Guy has specifically stated that nested RelativeLayouts have an exponential time for measurement.

See [video here at 38:08 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA#t=2284)

Answer (score -3):

actually all of them are based on the same class..
but it would be better to use according to me as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <at> here we just create nested more as we wont></at>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```