# layoutopt is missing

Tags: android

I knew layoutopt tools through the dev guide,but I can't find layoutopt tools in sdk tools directory.what's wrong? I use sdk manage to update all version of the tools.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Layoutopt has been replaced by a new tool called "lint". Lint is available as a command line tool (you can see it in your screenshot) and as a module in the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: you should update the documentation on google ffs http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html#layoutopt

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Android SDK manager and select, install all packages.